# Will linked moved apps to sd card through link2sd works after unrooted mobile?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, app2sd, unrooting, link2sd

Will linked moved apps to sd card through link2sd works after unrooted mobile?

I want to move my apps to external sd card of my android 6.0 mobile it has option of formatting sd card to internal memory but still out of 100 user apps installed it automove auto save 30 apps to internal formatted external micro sd card and 70 user apps auto installs still remains internal memory which are unmovable thus filled my internal memory

I once tried link2sd with 3-4 years before my old android 5.1 mobile device after rooting it. But it got problem after rooting through kingoroot as it was open and some.malware corrupted it I recovered it back through flash stock rom but didn't tried it again. Link2sd smoothly automatically moved linked apps to second partition but I kept the mobile opened and didnt unrooted it and some root permitted apps malware or cleaner corrupted or deleted some system file that old time.

[image]

I want to know if I again root my android 6 mobile with proper stock ROM backup through magisk or su or kingoroot and use link2sd or app2sd and install move or link user apps to micro sd card second or first partition and then unroot it will the linked or moved app work after unrooting mobile as link2sd script runs scripts on every booting of android in boot.init so technically it's possible to unroot after installing moving linking apps through link2sd or app2sd will android recognise link2sd linked apps without rooting privilages permissions after moving can we unroot it again.

I want to unroot to safe mobile from accidently deleting any system root files by cleaner or anitmalware or any malware infection for security